# Client still can ssh login without password on server after generating new keys

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

First I generated keys on client (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -f .ssh/id_rsa
```

then I copied it to server (Ubuntu Server 18.04)

```
$ ssh-copy-id 192.168.1.58
```

Now I can see the key in `.ssh/authirized_keys` on server and I can login without a password.

Then I generated new keys on client and previous keys were overwritten. But I can still login to server without a password. I was expecting since the keys have been changed, server wouldn't verify me. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I even removed keys

```
$ rm .ssh/id*
$ ls .ssh/
known_hosts
```

I can still login

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.58
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-91-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

System information as of Mon Mar 23 08:51:34 UTC 2020

System load:  0.0                Processes:              106
Usage of /:   42.8% of 12.31GB   Users logged in:        1
Memory usage: 6%                 IP address for enp0s3:  192.168.1.58
Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for docker0: 172.17.0.1


0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Mon Mar 23 08:46:19 2020 from 192.168.1.59

$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1[...]nr6eR33QK1BYeNT0BjyhRztd me@ubnutu-vm
$ w
08:53:57 up  2:10,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.02, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
me       tty1     -                07:12   21.00s  0.35s  0.32s -bash
me       pts/0    192.168.1.59     08:51    1.00s  0.06s  0.00s w
```

**Edit 2:**

This is from `ssh -v`:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:Db+pAR0Bc2kmZ9jju9zttSZDwfbEl4TM82AV7KSZ3DM /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.58 ([192.168.1.58]:22).
...
```

Although there is no `id_rsa` file in `/home/me/.ssh/` folder. So I thought that maybe some sort of cache is involved and after a reboot on client now I have to enter the password.

This is `ssh -v` after reboot:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
me@192.168.1.58's password:
```

So a reboot was needed.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with `ssh -v`? The verbose output will include the fingerprint of the key that has been accepted. You may then use `ssh-keygen -l -f keyfile` to print the fingerprint of your keys and find the matching one.

Comment: Do you have an SSH agent running, with that key loaded?

Comment: @muru I don't know how can I check?

Comment: `ssh-add -l` lists the added keys

Comment: Assuming you are willing to dig a bit further into the issue, you may post an answer to you question and, later, accept it. It may be useful to other users, but it'd require you to find out what was going on. E.g. does `ssh-add -l` list any cached keys? Is a `ssh-agent` process running (`pgrep -a ssh-agent` or `ps -ef | grep '[s]sh-agent'`)? Ideally, you should be able to reproduce what originally happened. Just a suggestion, no problem if you aren't going to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [@fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san)'s advise I dug a little deeper and This is what I got:

This is from https://www.ssh.com/ssh/agent

> By default, the agent uses SSH keys stored in the .ssh directory under
> the user's home directory. The ssh-add command is used for adding
> identities to the agent. In the simplest form, just run if without
> argument to add the default files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, .ssh/id_dsa,
> ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519, and ~/.ssh/identity. Otherwise,
> give it the name of the private key file to add as an argument.
>
> The following command will list private keys currently accessible to the agent:
>
> ```
> ssh-add -l
> ```

After connecting to the server the `ssh-add -l` shows this:

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:rzgw39XLAT0NHof4RBXFU/ahKhFWlH8FqMgNxBX2SAE /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

If the `id_*` keys in the `.ssh/` folder change or be deleted the `ssh-add -l` still shows the same output and it will be used for future connections (at least in my case).

At that point a reboot or one of the following commands will remove the cached key:

```
$ ssh-add -d /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity removed: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa (me@ubnutu-vm)
```

or

```
$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
```

Now password prompt will be shown for new connections.

**Update:**

This is from https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddKeysToAgent:

> **AddKeysToAgent**
>
> Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running
> ssh-agent(1). If this option is set to yes and a key is loaded from a
> file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the
> default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1). If this option is set to ask,
> ssh(1) will require confirmation using the SSH_ASKPASS program before
> adding a key (see ssh-add(1) for details). If this option is set to
> confirm, each use of the key must be confirmed, as if the -c option
> was specified to ssh-add(1). If this option is set to no, no keys are
> added to the agent. The argument must be **yes**, **confirm**, **ask**, or **no** (the
> default).

Comment: the option `AddKeysToAgent yes` would automatically add a key to the agent after first use. This option might perhaps be set elsewhere than the config file.

Comment: There is no `AddKeysToAgent` in SSH config [man page of Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), but there is one in [BSD's man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddKeysToAgent). That was helpful.

Comment: it all depends on the version. Here "on linux" (Debian): https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html#AddKeysToAgent